# Can PerformancePoint scorecards and reports be rendered as images?

Tags: performancepoint

Sorry if this question seems naive, but I am a complete PerformancePoint newbie. Is it possible to programmatically render a PerformancePoint 2010 scorecard or report as an image? I was initially hoping there might be a web service or PPS API method that could accomplish this, but I haven't been able to come up with anything so far.

Thanks in advance,
Jason

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, Performance Point reports are available as WebPart. Once you create reports from Performance Point Server you can deploy it to the SharePoint site. After you deploy it to SharePoint site you can deploy each report as "PerformancePoint Dashboard Item Web Part".